# How to fix header file error?

Tags: c++, header, c++builder

So, my question is how to fix some error in header file, to run program normally? For example I use c++ builder 2010 and when winuser.h file is included, the program always get error like this

> Checking project dependencies...
>   Compiling Project7.cbproj (Debug
>   configuration) [BCC32 Error]
>   winuser.h(47): E2257 , expected   Full
>   parser context
>       File6.cpp(4): #include c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\rad
>   studio\7.0\include\winuser.h [BCC32
>   Error] winuser.h(48): E2257 , expected
>   Full parser context

i try to replace that file with original from default installation, but that still get same error, how to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message is hard to read but the actual error is "E2257 , expected" (coma expected)

From the RAD studio documentation:

```
A comma was expected in a list of declarations, initializations, or parameters.

This problem is often caused by a missing syntax element earlier in the file 
or one of its included headers.
```

The error message give you the line where it happened and you should probably look before that. There is probably some '}', ')' or ';' or other syntaxic closer missing in your code just before the error (likely before inclusion of the header file in your code). Full error message (you truncated it) or actual code would make it easier to spot.

It is also possible, even if unlikely, that the error is in one of the headers included in `winuser.h`.

Comment: extern "C" {
#endif /* __cplusplus */

#ifndef WINVER
#define WINVER  0x0500      /* version 5.0 */
#endif /* !WINVER */

#include <stdarg.h>

#ifndef NOUSER

typedef HANDLE HDWP;
typedef VOID MENUTEMPLATEA;

Comment: try putting <winuser.h> as first include. I would bet for some macro definition conflict between headers.

Comment: I would bet for some.... and you will win :), for some reason when i include windows.h file before winuser.h file it work's fine, but if do same thing just reverse, that didn't ...thnx

Answer (score 4):

The error is almost certainly caused by whatever code appears *before* line 4 of File6.cpp.  Most likely that is another header file, in which case it is likely that the code therein is malformed - a missing semicolon or brace for example.

The quickest way to verify that winuser.h is not the issue is to change the order of inclusion so that winuser.h is included first.

Another possibility is that something in winuser.h is dependent on some other header not previously included or directly included in winuser.h.  Most Win32 API headers are included by windows.h, and it is generally advisable to include windows,h rather than either of [its children](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows.h#Child_header_files).

Comment: so if i understand you as well, you say that even if i don't include winuser.h file (but with included windows.h only) that can use all the function which is stored in winuser.h without any problem ?

Comment: @raptor: yes, usually <windows.h> is enough and includes <winuser.h>

Comment: @raptor: Yes that is exactly what I am saying, and this is also the recommended method.  For example take a look at the Win32 API documentation for a winuser function such as MessageBox (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for example; at the bottom it tells you what header file the function is included in, and what header file to include - they are not the same, it says **"Header: Winuser.h (include Windows.h)"**.  Also *follow the link* in my answer, it explains exactly that!

Comment: @Clifford: what is rather surprising is that these MS headers apparently do not includes watchdogs to allow to include them in any orders the way it's usually done on unixes.

Comment: @kriss: That's because they're not intended for directly inclusion at all. They're an implementation detail of `Windows.h`